# Problems with start service automatically on boot

Tags: raspbian, pi-4, systemd, services

I'm developping a dotnet core service to run in rpi4, and when i execute the service with "dotnet run rpiservice.dll" the code executes normally. So, i created a .service file and insert in /etc/systemd/system folder. Here's my file:

```
[Unit]
Description=ANA Service

[Service]
ExecStart=/opt/dotnet/dotnet RpiGateway.dll
WorkingDirectory=/home/stationpi/RpiGateway
Restart=always
RestartSec=10
User=stationpi


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when i reboot rpi the service doesn't started. When i check the status with "systemctl status rpi.service" returns me "inactive(dead)".

I try many things, and when i change the WantedBy to "default.target" the service started normally on boot.

Anyone knows why multi-user.target doesn't work? Many tutorials that teach how to create a service in rpi use multi-user.target.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone knows why multi-user.target doesn't work? Many tutorials that teach how to create a service in rpi use multi-user.target.

Likely because `multi-user.target` is not the default target; if you installed from the "full" (ie., not "lite") version of Rpi OS, the default will be graphical.target.

You can check this with:

```
> systemctl get-default
```

If you want to change it:

```
> sudo systemctl set-default multi-user
```

However, unless you have some particular reason to do that, you might as well leave it the way it is.  It's also usually best to use `WantedBy=default.target` as that will match the active target regardless of whether it is graphical or multi-user or whatever.

Comment: thanks for the explanation!